# angular call http request to the function ng-repeat return

Tags: javascript, angularjs, http

I would like to call a function in mg-repeat and this function call a http request with id for find list data  but when i try this i have one error message this.

this a call of function :

```
<div ng-repeat="ListeReponse in reponsefonction(Listechamps.keyQuestion)" >
    <label class="col-xs-4 control-label">
        {{ListeReponse.reponse}}
    </label>
</div>
```

this is a function :

```
$scope.reponsefonction  = function(idQuestion)
{
    var defer = $q.defer();
    return RequestService.get('question/'+idQuestion+'/reponse').success(function(data) 
    { 
        defer.resolve(data);
    })
    return defer.promise;
}
```

My Service :

```
app.factory('RequestService', function ($http, WEB_SERVICE_URL) 
{
    var requestService = {};
    requestService.get = function (type) 
    {
        var response = $http.get(WEB_SERVICE_URL.url+type);
        return response;
    };

    // ajout
    requestService.post = function (type, data) 
    {
        var response = $http.post(WEB_SERVICE_URL.url+type, data);
        return response;
    };

    requestService.put = function (type, data) 
    {
        var response = $http.put(WEB_SERVICE_URL.url+type, data);
        return response;
    };

    return requestService;
})
```

error message :

> docs.angularjs.org/error/$rootScope/infdig?p0=10&p1=%5B%5D

Comment: FYI, that error message is actually a link. there's a description if you open it which says: `10 $digest() iterations reached. Aborting!`. so there has to be an infinite loop somewhere.

Comment: and in addition to all other comments: in your function which calls the api - you have 2 returns! return the request + the promise. remove the return before "RequestService"... then it is perfect. and as others already mentioned: instead of passing a promise to the view, set the data to a scope / vm variable and use this in the view. ng-repeat will start and re-render its self after every change.

Comment: i remove the return i hava always a probléme

Answer (score 0):

You created an infitie loop. Each call will trigger another call. Angular evaluates the responseFunction everytime the calls return. You will need to re-work your app a little:

Do not call a function in ng-repeat. Instead simply link it a to a variable. Fill the variable once on startup with a get query.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think ng-repeat works with promises. In this case the ng-repeat is looping through "null/undefined" which causes this error.

Try this:

html:

```
<div ng-repeat="ListeReponse in getResponses(Listechamps.keyQuestion)" >
    <label class="col-xs-4 control-label">{{ListeReponse.reponse}}</label></div>
```

controller:

```
var idQuestions = {}; // keep track of the entire list
$scope.getResponses = function(idQuestion) {
  var notInitialized = idQuestions[idQuestion] == null;
  idQuestions[idQuestion] = notInitialized ? [] : idQuestions[idQuestion]; // initialize to empty array
  if (notInitialized) {
    $scope.reponsefonction(idQuestion); //kicks off ajax request to get data
  }
  return idQuestions[idQuestion];
}

$scope.reponsefonction = function(idQuestion) {
  RequestService.get('question/' + idQuestion + '/reponse').success(function(data) {
      //assuming data is an []
      Array.prototype.push.apply(idQuestions[idQuestion], data); //update the same array object to prevent multiple $digest cycles

    }
  }
}
```

Comment: TypeError: Array.prototype.push called on null or undefined
    at crmController.js:53
    at angular.js:10296
    at processQueue (angular.js:14792)
    at angular.js:14808
    at Scope.$eval (angular.js:16052)
    at Scope.$digest (angular.js:15870)
    at Scope.$apply (angular.js:16160)
    at done (angular.js:10589)
    at completeRequest (angular.js:10787)
    at XMLHttpRequest.requestLoaded (angular.js:10728)

Comment: Uncaught Error: [$rootScope:infdig] 10 $digest() iterations reached. Aborting!
Watchers fired in the last 5 iterations: []
http://errors.angularjs.org/1.4.8/$rootScope/infdig?p0=10&p1=%5B%5D

Comment: TypeError: Array.prototype.push called on null or undefined at crmController.js:53 at angular.js:10296 at processQueue (angular.js:14792) at angular.js:14808 at Scope.$eval (angular.js:16052) at Scope.$digest (angular.js:15870) at Scope.$apply (angular.js:16160) at done (angular.js:10589) at completeRequest (angular.js:10787) at XMLHttpRequest.requestLoaded (angular.js:10728) –

Comment: seems like idQuestions[idQuestion] was null. Make sure you html ng-repeat is calling getResponse() and not responseFonction()

Comment: thanks but i thinks it very slow wen we hare lot of data ? it not more do this ?    $scope.question = [];
                RequestService.get('question').success(function(data) { 
                    $scope.question = data;
                    if(!$scope.$$phase) {
                        $scope.$apply();
                    }
                });

Comment: $scope.reponse = [];
                RequestService.get('reponse').success(function(data) { 
                    $scope.question = data;
                    
                    $scope.question = $filter('GetCollection')( $scope.question ,data,"keyReponse","Question.KeyQuestion","reponse");
                     console.log($scope.question)
                    if(!$scope.$$phase) {
                        $scope.$apply();
                    }
                } );

Comment: app.filter('GetCollection', function() {
    return function(collectionMain, Collection,idMain,Idcollection,List) {
       
  

    for(var i=0; i<Collection.length ;i++){
            for(var j=0; j<collectionMain.length ;j++){
                
                console.log(collectionMain[j]["question"]);
                console.log(Collection[i][Idcollection]);
              //  if(collectionMain[j][idMain] == Collection[i][Idcollection]){
              //collectionMain[j][List].push(Collection[i]);
              //  }
            }  
        }    
    }
    return this.collectionMain;
});

Comment: if you have a multiple questions to display at the same time, then you'll be overriding your $scope.question.